# What's wrong with my INSERT statement? 44

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, insert, while-loop, do-while

I am using SQL Server 2008 and want to create a procedure that simply takes the data from one table and inserts it into another table.  Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE consomVspPools (@start DATE, @end DATE)
AS
CREATE TABLE dbo.temp (pool NVARCHAR (250), endUsedCapacityInKB FLOAT, 
                         startUsedCapacityInKB FLOAT)
WHILE (@end >= @start)
BEGIN
      INSERT INTO temp
      SELECT pool, MAX(capacityInKB), MAX(freeCapacityInKB)
      FROM Vsp_Pool
      WHERE dateCollecte IN (DATEADD(day, -1, @end), @end)
      GROUP BY pool
      SET @end = DATEADD(day, -1, @end)
END
SELECT *
FROM temp
DROP TABLE dbo.temp
```

I know right now the code doesn't really do much, but I had to simplify it a lot to narrow my mistake (which didn't helped me much anyway).  The error I get says:

"Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition"

I'm new to SQL so this might be obvious but I don't see it, everything seems in order to me.

EDIT1:

so this is the code I know have, upgraded as suggested:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE consomVspPools (@start DATE, @end DATE)
AS
CREATE TABLE #dbo.temp (pool NVARCHAR (250), endUsedCapacityInKB FLOAT, 
                      startUsedCapacityInKB FLOAT)
WHILE (@end >= @start)
BEGIN
      INSERT INTO temp (pool, endUsedCapacityInKB, startUsedCapacityInKB)
      SELECT pool, MAX(capacityInKB), MAX(freeCapacityInKB)
      FROM Vsp_Pool
      WHERE dateCollecte IN (DATEADD(day, -1, @end), @end)
      GROUP BY pool
      SET @end = DATEADD(day, -1, @end)
END
SELECT *
FROM temp
DROP TABLE #dbo.temp
```

But this then gives me the folowwing error:

"Invalid column name 'pool' "

Just FYI, pool is present in the table Vsp_Pool as well as in temp.

Comment: I'd start by using some best practices - fully qualify your objects (database.schema.temp, database.schema.vsp_pool), list your insert columns (`INSERT INTO database.schema.temp (pool, endUsedCapacityInKB, startUsedCapacityInKB) SELECT ...`), and use a temp table: `CREATE TABLE #Temp...`

Comment: One other thing. This is in a procedure and you are creating a persistent table. This procedure will fail the second time it is run because the table temp will already exist. I would recommend changing that to a temp table. create table #temp...

Comment: I just noticed you also drop the table at the end. Ugh!!! No need for a persistent table or even a temp one. Just select the data you want in a single select statement.

Comment: Like I said, this is a very simplified version of the code, I can't select all I want in one statement.  I will need to do calculations on the columns with another software and based on everything I know about SQL (which ain't much I'll admit) the calculations I want to perform cannot be done with SQL.  So I'd rather just have the columns in the table like this and work from there.

Comment: @user3779627, do not under any circumstances create a permananent table in a stored proc. This is simply a bad practice. Learn to use temp tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to include the column names in your "insert into" statement.

```
INSERT INTO temp (poolVal, maxcapacity, maxfreecapacity)
```

might help to give the column names in the select statement aliases like in my example.#

pool is a keyword use anything else for your field name.

Comment: Actually, while that certainly is a best practice, it isn't technically required.  I had to test it out to be sure, but I was able to insert without listing the column names.

Comment: if I do this I then get a "syntax error near the keyword WHERE"

Comment: @Dave.Gugg, it is required if there are more columns than the ones he is adding (columns that will be null). And It is something that I would never pass in code review anyway. You need to be able to tell that the column you aer insterting will match up exactly with the column you are inserting into. It is irresponsible to ever write an insert statment where you do not list the columns. You will have data integrity problems when if you do this and it goes well beyond a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
Put if condition because while is in infinite loop:


CREATE PROCEDURE consomVspPools (@start DATE, @end DATE)
AS
CREATE TABLE dbo.temp (pool NVARCHAR (250), endUsedCapacityInKB FLOAT, 
                         startUsedCapacityInKB FLOAT)
if (@end >= @start)
BEGIN
      INSERT INTO temp
      SELECT pool, MAX(capacityInKB), MAX(freeCapacityInKB)
      FROM Vsp_Pool
      WHERE (dateCollecte >= (DATEADD(day, -1, @end)) and  (dateCollecte <= @end)
      GROUP BY pool
      SET @end = DATEADD(day, -1, @end)
END
SELECT *
FROM temp
DROP TABLE dbo.temp
```

Comment: I think the loop is fine since I'm decreasing the value of @end after each iteration of the loop with SET

Comment: Just check with solution

Answer (score -1):

You may have heard that SQL is a declarative language, not a procedural one. What this means is that you should, instead of saying *how* to do something, declare *what* you want to do. The SQL engine optimizes for this behavior. WHILE statements are generally not used for this reason. Not knowing your database structure, my best guess is to say that instead, you should try something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE consomVspPools (@start DATE, @end DATE)
AS

BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM
        (
        SELECT dateCollecte, pool, MAX(capacityInKB), MAX(freeCapacityInKB)
        FROM Vsp_Pool 

        -- Is "dateCollecte" a typo? Might be your issue.
        WHERE dateCollecte BETWEEN @start AND @end
        GROUP BY dateCollecte, pool
        )
END
```

Check out the [BETWEEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx) statement. Also note that I'm querying from a query result and avoiding the temp table entirely. The takeaway here is to start thinking in sets. If a query feels like you're going through and atomically updating each entry individually instead of as a set, there's probably a better, SQL optimized way of rewriting it.

Comment: well for the sample code I have here you're right this would be better, but for what I have to do it won't do.  Like I said I simplified the code a lot just to know my mistake in the INSERT but I've tried the BETWEEN (it was my first thought) but it's not oding exactly what I'm aiming for.

Comment: Then my guess would be to use the column names in the INSERT statement like @user3195030 said and then change the typo in your WHERE statement. I'm pretty sure "dateCollecte" should be "dateCollected" am I wrong?

Comment: Also, maybe change the IN statement to two equals statements
    `WHERE dateCollected == DATEADD(day, -1, @end) OR dateCollected == @end`

Comment: if you check the edit I have added the column names as suggested and dateCollecte is not a typo, it's French ah ah!  And I will try the equals but I've used IN before and it worked very well...